# need your help for the following vhdl code in Xilinx tool

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity conv_enc is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           inp : in  STD_LOGIC;
           outp : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWN TO 0));
end conv_enc;

architecture Behavioral of conv_enc is
begin
 process
 variable ff:std_logic_vector(3 down to 0);
  begin
   wait until rising_edge (clk)
     if rst='1' then
      ff<="0000";
     else
      for i in 2 down to 0 loop
       ff(i)<=ff(i+1);
        end loop;
        ff(3)<=inp;
    end if;
 end process;
 outp(0) <= inp xor ff(1) xor ff(0) ;
 outp(1) <= inp xor ff(3) xor ff(2) xor ff(1) ;
 outp(2) <= inp xor ff(3) xor ff(2) xor ff(1) xor ff(0);
 end Behavioral;
```

THE ERROR SAYS:
HDLParsers:3481 - Library work has no units. Did not save reference file "xst/work/hdllib.ref" for it.
PLEASE HELP

Comment: You should not use `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` or `STD_LOGIC_ARITH`; your code does not perform any arithmetic, and even if it did, you would use `numeric_std` package for this.

Answer (score 3):

While Maria and scary_jeff give partial solutions there are several errors:

> You declared a range `down to` instead of `downto` in three places.
>
> You missed a semicolon terminating the wait statement in the process.
>
> You attempt to read a variable outside of a process (outside it's scope).

The following is your code correcting these, notably making ff a signal:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
-- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity conv_enc is
    port (
        clk:   in  std_logic;
        rst:   in  std_logic;
        inp:   in  std_logic;
        outp:  out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) -- WAS DOWN TO
    );
end entity conv_enc;

architecture behavioral of conv_enc is
     signal ff:   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- variable used outside process
begin
    process
        -- variable ff:   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  --  was down to
    begin
        wait until rising_edge (clk);  -- was miaaing terminating semicolon
        if rst = '1' then
            ff <= "0000";
        else
            for i in 2 downto 0 loop   -- was down to
                ff(i) <= ff(i + 1);
            end loop;
            ff(3) <= inp;
        end if;
    end process;

    outp(0) <= inp xor ff(1) xor ff(0);
    outp(1) <= inp xor ff(3) xor ff(2) xor ff(1);
    outp(2) <= inp xor ff(3) xor ff(2) xor ff(1) xor ff(0);

 end architecture behavioral;
```

Note the unused Synopsys packages are commented out.

Your code then analyzes.

Note there is no assignment to outp(3).

Your [convolutionally encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code#Convolutional_encoding) doesn't look quite right, but that could just be me.

Without a testbench providing stimuli and expected results the functionality can't be validated.

Answer (score 0):

The `ff(3)<=inp;` must be right after the `else`.